# My TOR connection keeps timing out

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection

here is my TOR log, someone please help

```
2/13/19, 17:26:00.670 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/13/19, 17:26:00.670 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
2/13/19, 17:26:00.670 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
2/13/19, 17:26:00.671 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
2/13/19, 17:26:00.985 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
2/13/19, 17:26:02.653 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
2/13/19, 17:26:02.818 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
2/13/19, 17:26:47.848 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later). 
2/13/19, 17:26:49.141 [NOTICE] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Tor service you are trying to connect to is down. You should try later, or contact the server operator

Also, you should try restarting Tor browser: it may be a bad circuit